# Encrypt entire Linux drive with TrueCrypt

Tags: linux, encryption, truecrypt

I've found plenty of info online about how to encrypt a drive with TrueCrypt, but everything I found was either outdated or not for Linux.

Here's what I'm after: I want to encrypt my entire drive (except, of course, the part[s] of it I CAN'T encrypt because they're needed to boot). I don't wish to reinstall my OS unless absolutely necessary.

Could someone please tell me how to encrypt my entire drive on Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) with TrueCrypt (7.0a)?

Comment: You might find that LUKS is easier to use.  Both Debian and Ubuntu can as part of the text installer setup full disk encryption using LUKS.  I am not ware of any current linux full disk encryption method that can be enabled post-install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the "alternative" Ubuntu installation disc and using the encryption option they have at setup time. I did end up having to reinstall my OS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

http://xercestech.com/full-system-encryption-for-linux.geek

Basically, AES / LUKS support is in GRUB2 nowadays, but you need to compile it yourself (or at least back in March you had to).

No need to re-install!!! Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

http://grub.enbug.org/TrueCrypt

and read this:  https://superuser.com/questions/179526/how-to-chain-grub2-for-ubuntu-10-04-from-truecrypt-its-bootloader-multi-boot-a

Comment: These really don't do anything for Linux.  Both those are about just including the truecrypt boot-loader for a windows partition in GRUB.